# C++ inheritance with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

EDIT: This is just another case "silly & uninteresting mistake". You've been warned :)

Here's something that's been keeping me up at night. Maybe someone with higher C++ knowledge can find how to get this to work:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
    virtual void Method ( T* arg ) = 0;
};

class Child : public Base<MyType>
{
    void Method ( MyType* arg ) { /*blah*/ };
};
```

This doesn't compile (at least on VS2008 it doesn't) because it can't match the two Methods together.

Currently we get around it by using a BaseType instead of MyType in the Method declaration and then cast BaseType to MyType in the Child implementation of the Method (We still need the MyType as a template for other stuff inside the base class).

Still it would be nice to be able to use the templated type directly.

EDIT:
Thanks guys it seems that fixing other errors (that were listed after) made it all work.
I did have `template<class T>` instead of `template<T>` in my original code as well as the Method listed as public.
It shows that I should have waited longer before posting. I apologize for that.

Comment: You will have pretty different errors with this code. Please post your actual code or at least something that compiles with the same errors you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is full example that compiles and works fine :

```
struct MyType
{
};

template< class T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Method ( T* arg ) = 0;
};

class Child : public Base<MyType>
{
  public:
    void Method ( MyType*  ) { /*blah*/ };
};


int main()
{
  MyType a;
  Child b;

  b.Method( &a );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the correct syntax in the first class template:

```
template<typename T> // here! You can also use "class" instead of "typename".
class Base
{
    virtual void Method ( T* arg ) = 0;
};
```

and your second class has to be a class template, unless `MyType` is a type:

```
template <typename MyType>
class Child : public Base<MyType>
{
    void Method ( MyType* arg ) { /*blah*/ };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first line write `template<class T>` instead of `template<T>`. That'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

For your desired result you need to make the base class method public

```
   template<class T> class Base
    {
        public: // public definition is important or else it won't be overridden
        virtual void Method ( T* arg ) {
            cout << "Method in base.";
        }
    };

class Child : public Base<char>
{
    void Method ( char* arg ) {
       cout << "Method in child.";
    };
};
```